# How to persist foreground service with geolocation service longer?

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

I have created a foreground service that gets user's geolocation after every 2 seconds the service than calculates the speed and performs some operation, the problem is application stops working after 24 hr and does not crash ( notification still in notification area remain ) and does not work in Oppo phones at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

**Here is the code for my service**

```
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;

import static java.lang.Math.acos;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;

public class drivingService extends Service implements LocationListener {

    // Declaration of Initialized Variables
    public static int PRIMARY_FOREGROUND_NOTIF_SERVICE_ID = 1001,   //Declaration of integers
            progress = 0;
    public static boolean enabled = true,                           //Declaration of boolean flags
            popupEnabled = false,
            sent = false,
            first = true,
            locked = false,
            removed = false,
            popup_visible = false,
            tmp_visible = false;
    // Declaration of Uninitialized Variables
    public static NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    private static String TAG = "LOCATION_THINGS";                  //Declaration of strings
    private static String id = "";
    public int drive = 0,
            stop = 0;
    public double lat1, lat2, lng1, lng2;
    public long time1, time2;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationManagerCompat cNotificationManager;
    Database db;
    WindowManager windowManager;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;                //Declaration of location manager
    private ImageView popup, stopping;
    boolean networkStatus;

    //Returns true and false idf the device is locked or not
    public static boolean isDeviceLocked(Context context) {
        boolean isLocked = false;

        // First we check the locked state
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        boolean inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode = keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();

        if (inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode) {
            isLocked = true;

        } else {
            // If password is not set in the settings, the inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode() returns false,
            // so we need to check if screen on for this case
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
                isLocked = !powerManager.isInteractive();
            } else {
                //noinspection deprecation
                isLocked = !powerManager.isScreenOn();
            }
        }
        return isLocked;
    }

    //Create notification for service
    public void createSimpleNotification() {
        String GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.blitzapp.textriteDriverAlert.not";
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), id)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.not)
                .setContentTitle("TextRite")
                .setContentText("TextRite - Drive Mode is Enabled")
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    }

    //Runs service powered by notification
    public void renderNotification() {
        cNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        cNotificationManager.notify(PRIMARY_FOREGROUND_NOTIF_SERVICE_ID, notification.build());
        startForeground(PRIMARY_FOREGROUND_NOTIF_SERVICE_ID, notification.build());
    }

    //Creates Notification Channel
    public void createNotificationChannel() {
        id = "_channel_01";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, "TextRite - Drive Mode is Enabled", importance);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

    }

    private void addToLogs(double speed, boolean alert, boolean tmp, boolean netwrok) {
        try {
            File root = new File(getFilesDir(), "speed_logs");
            Log.d("Address", "" + getFilesDir());

            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdir();
            }

            File filepath = new File(root, "logs.txt");

            if (!filepath.exists()) {
                filepath.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filepath, true);
            writer.append("Time->" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "==|| Speed->" + speed + " || Alert Visible->" + alert + " || Temp Visible->" + tmp +"Network Status"+networkStatus+" || DB Count"+Database.dbCount+"\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("File_I/O", "" + ex);
        }
    }

    //Runs only once when the service is created
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        try {

            createNotificationChannel();
            createSimpleNotification();
            renderNotification();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //Event Emitter to stop service
    private void sendEvent() {
        MainApplication application = (MainApplication) this.getApplication();
        ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost = application.getReactNativeHost();
        ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager();
        ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
        if (reactContext != null) {
            reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                    .emit("stopService", null);
        }
    }

    //This function is not used through out the code it is just added because of parent class service
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    //Adds alert to db when screen is locked
    public void addAlert() {
        try {
            boolean networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable();
            String alert = new Alert().getJsonObject();
            db.insertAlert(alert);
            if (networkStatus == true) {
                db.sendData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error Occurred while sending alerts to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //Runs every time the service is started
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        try {
            //Initialize database
            db = new Database(getApplicationContext());

//            Check If Force Stop button is presses
            if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("STOP")) {
                stopForeground(true);
                onDestroy();

            } else {
//            Check if switch is enabled then register location listener and create popup to render later
                if (enabled) {
                    try {
                        getLocation();
                        createPopup();
                        //If any kind of mishap occurs report the user via toast message
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // if switch not open by user then stop service
                } else {
                    stopForeground(true);
                    onDestroy();
                }
            }
            //If any kind of mishap occurs report the user via toast message
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some Error Occurred while starting the service.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    //Start the listener
    private void getLocation() {
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to request location update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS provider does not exist ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //Take true or false in argument to render popup
    public void clearAll() {
        showTemp(false);
        removed = true;
        popupEnabled = false;
    }

    public void showPopup(boolean show) {
        if (show == true) {
            try {
                stopping.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            popup_visible = true;
            popupEnabled = true;
        } else {
            popup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            popup_visible = false;
        }

    }

    public void showTemp(boolean show) {
        if (show == true) {
            try {
                popup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            popupEnabled = true;
            stopping.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tmp_visible = true;
        } else {
            stopping.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tmp_visible = false;
        }

    }

    //Creates popup or the alert window
    private void createPopup() {
        int LAYOUT_TYPE;

        //Layout Parameters Declared
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        //Setting Layout type According to build version of phone
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_TYPE = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_TYPE = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE;
        }

        //Setting Up Layout Type and other properties
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.type = LAYOUT_TYPE;
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;

        //Check if Service is enabled by user then create popup set its visibility to false for later use
        try {
            if (enabled) {
                //Window Manager Initialized
                windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

                //Setting properties and parameters of popup to be viewed
                popup = new ImageView(this);
                popup.setImageResource(R.drawable.alert_potrait);
                popup.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                stopping = new ImageView(this);
                stopping.setImageResource(R.drawable.stopping);
                stopping.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                windowManager.addView(popup, params);
                windowManager.addView(stopping, params);
                popup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                stopping.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            //If any kind of mishap occurs report the user via toast message
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some Error Occurred while creating Overlay Screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //Runs when is stopped
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        try {
            //set enabled service by user to false
            enabled = false;
            //disable popup visibility
            popup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Unregister location manager for updates if it's not null
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }
            //send Event to React Native that service has stopped
            sendEvent();
            stopSelf();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error Occurred, Restart your phone to avoid any inconvenience", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    //Location Manager Initialization to access location listener
    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    //Returns true and false is network is connected or not
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    //Runs Every 2 second and returns the current location of the device
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // check if location is not null or value is not a garbage value

        if (location != null) {
            //setting up variables to calculate speed
            lat2 = lat1;
            lng2 = lng1;
            time2 = time1;
            lat1 = location.getLatitude();
            lng1 = location.getLongitude();
            time1 = location.getTime();

            //calculations performed
            double distance = getDistance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2);
            double time = calcTime(time1, time2);
            double speed = distance / time;
            Log.d("error: ",location.toString());

            try {
                networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable();
                if (networkStatus == true) {
                   JSONObject log;
                    log = new JSONObject();
                    log.put("type","location_inside_if");
                    log.put("location_object",location.toString());
                    log.put("latitude",location.getLatitude());
                    log.put("longitude",location.getLongitude());
                    log.put("get_speed",speed);
                    log.put("speed_calculated",location.getSpeed());
                    log.put("drive",drive);
                    log.put("stop",stop);
                    log.put("locked",locked);
                    Log.d("Location_object", log.toString());
                    db.sendLogsData(log);
                    db.sendData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }


            //if speed is greater than 8
            if (speed >= 8) {
                drive++;
                stop = 0;
                if (locked == true) {
                    locked = false;
                    showPopup(true);
                } else {
                    if (drive == 5) {
                        showPopup(true);
                        drive = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            // if speed in less than 8
            else {
                drive = 0;
                stop++;
                popup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (locked == true) {
                    //Log.d("Log_Lock", "JUST AFTER UNLOCK: locked = true");
                    locked = false;
                    if (stop >= 25 && tmp_visible == true) {
                        if (tmp_visible) {
                            //Log.d("Log_Lock", "JUST AFTER UNLOCK: temp time up / back to normal");
                            clearAll();
                            stop = 0;
                        }
                    } else if (stop == 0) {
                        if (popup_visible) {
                            showTemp(true);
                            Log.d("Log_Lock", "JUST AFTER UNLOCK: timer running");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //Log.d("Log_Lock", "JUST AFTER UNLOCK: locked = false " + popupEnabled + " " + popup_visible + " " + tmp_visible);
                    if (popup_visible) {
                        //Log.d("Log_Lock", "AFTER SOMETIME: show temp popup");
                        showPopup(false);
                        showTemp(true);
                        drive = 0;

                    } else if (tmp_visible) {
                        showTemp(true);
                        if (stop >= 25) {
                            //Log.d("Log_Lock", "AFTER SOMETIME: temp time up");
                            clearAll();
                            stop = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        clearAll();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isDeviceLocked(getApplicationContext())) {
                popup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                stopping.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                locked = true;
                if (sent == false) {
                    addAlert();
                    sent = true;
                }
            } else {
                sent = false;
            }
        }else{
            try {
                networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable();
                if (networkStatus == true) {
                    JSONObject log;
                    log = new JSONObject();
                    log.put("type","inside_location_null");
                     log.put("location_object",location.toString());
                    log.put("drive",drive);
                    log.put("stop",stop);
                    log.put("locked",locked);
                    db.sendLogsData(log);
                    db.sendData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        try {
            networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable();
            if (networkStatus == true) {
                JSONObject log;
                log = new JSONObject();
                log.put("type","onStatusChanged");
                log.put("provider",provider);
                log.put("status",status);
                log.put("extras",extras);
                log.put("drive",drive);
                log.put("stop",stop);
                log.put("locked",locked);
                db.sendLogsData(log);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        try {
            networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable();
            if (networkStatus == true) {
                JSONObject log;
                log = new JSONObject();
                log.put("type","onProviderEnabled");
                log.put("provider",provider);
                log.put("drive",drive);
                log.put("stop",stop);
                log.put("locked",locked);
                db.sendLogsData(log);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        try {
            networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable();
            if (networkStatus == true) {
                JSONObject log;
                log = new JSONObject();
                log.put("type","onProviderDisabled");
                log.put("provider",provider);
                log.put("drive",drive);
                log.put("stop",stop);
                log.put("locked",locked);
                db.sendLogsData(log);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    //Returns the distance between two locations
    double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double M_PI = Math.PI;
        // Convert degrees to radians
        lat1 = lat1 * M_PI / 180.0;
        lon1 = lon1 * M_PI / 180.0;
        lat2 = lat2 * M_PI / 180.0;
        lon2 = lon2 * M_PI / 180.0;

        // radius of earth in metres
        double r = 6378100;

        // P
        double rho1 = r * cos(lat1);
        double z1 = r * sin(lat1);
        double x1 = rho1 * cos(lon1);
        double y1 = rho1 * sin(lon1);

        // Q
        double rho2 = r * cos(lat2);
        double z2 = r * sin(lat2);
        double x2 = rho2 * cos(lon2);
        double y2 = rho2 * sin(lon2);

        // Dot product
        double dot = (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2 + z1 * z2);
        double cos_theta = dot / (r * r);
        double theta = acos(cos_theta);

        // Distance in Metres
        Log.d("Dist DISTANCE", Double.toString(r * theta));
        return r * theta;
    }

    //Returns time in milliseconds between two locations
    private double calcTime(double t1, double t2) {
        Log.d("DIS_DIFF", Double.toString((t1 - t2) / 1000));
        return (t1 - t2) / 1000;
    }
```

}

Comment: Please post your code in order to help you.

Comment: added service code

Comment: IDK what exactly the issue is where the window manager in service or a non sticky start. You should try logging your catch statements before assuming that there's no crash

Comment: On One Plus devices, the system would still force stop a foreground service. To avoid it on those devices, one the app switcher there is a "lock" icon on the app top right. This stops it from being destroyed. Perhaps there is something similar on Oppo?

Comment: @StuStirling yes Oppo has some battery optimisation settings that stops the service in minutes after it was started